# Graphic content

Tags: discussion

I know that posting erotic stuff is forbidden in here (13+ age for registering)

How about posting graphical content with a warning/spoiler?

Example

As a reference watch this video:

> Warning! The following link leads to a very graphic video. Please proceed with caution!
>  [Genocyber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXZ2bTigdGY)

Comment: In my honest opinion nudity should not be a taboo for kids while violence should not be tolerated. So if nudity is out of the window violence should be even more out of the picture.

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view, this popped up just a few days ago on the main site when someone asked a question about why there were so few on-screen deaths of children in movies. Naturally, many people provided links to YouTube videos and the like which showed clips from films (e.g. The Shining) to disprove this.

Ultimately, as long as the clips in reference are related to the question and their posting is justified given the context of the question, I think they are acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

We should be aware that StackExchange allows anyone from the age of 13 to open an account.  This means we should always be aware of the content of our posts, including:

- Bad language
- Drug & Alcohol Use
- Sexual content
- Violence

I think any post that potentially includes content that directly could exceed the bounds that our 'example 13 year-old user' shouldn't really be exposed to, then first of all try to avoid that content at all, but if unavoidable to ask or answer a question - then I think using spoiler markup is appropriate.

However please note that I would consider the average 13 year old to be aware that these things exist (language, drug use, sex, violence etc) and to be able to read and learn about why movies and TV shows include such themes - so we're not in the business of avoiding discussing these themes, just potentially avoiding having such content directly in posts.

Yes, I know that everyone's opinion of that will vary - but just be sensitive to other people's point of view, and if someone edits your post to spoiler something like that, or flags it for me to do the same - then don't get upset.

Answer (score 2):

In america nudity is usually censored while violence is not. My wife and I personally allow our kids to watch just about anything from kids movies to full on horror, but if any parts have nudity, we skip over them or if the movie is too sexually explicit, they can't participate or we change the movie.

My point is that everyone has their own opinion as to what should be censored. If a question requires explicit content then I like your suggestion of trying to sensor it, but if someone wants to hover over, then they will. Can't stop them.

But, for those of us who participate in the site while at work or in a public place, the 'spoiler alert' edits would go a long way to preventing NSFW posts.

Comment: What do you tell your kids when they ask where are children from? T̶a̶l̶e̶s̶ lies about storks, cabbage fields, bees and so on? Or just "wait X years"?

Comment: I treat my kids like adults, not idiots. I explain the truth in an appropriate manner.